# Adding items to the Tags categories in DotNetNuke?

Tags: tags, dotnetnuke, taxonomy

I know that recently Tags in DNN are stored in Taxonomy table (Categories) and Folksonomy (User Tags), well, i know how to add the Tags categories from Admin settings, but where do i add the Tags itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

admin -> taxonomy -> {click edit pencil on the vocabulary you want to add terms for} -> {click add term button}